# oracle forms creating fancy search (pl/sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have one fancy idea to make a search through Oracle Forms within my tables. So I can do it easy with one way: user types FULL *criteria value* and execute it. Saying 'criteria value' I mean that user can search for example Employee within his name. What I am aiming now is when user put for example first letter 'J' in search field, i want to spread list with all employees who name started with 'J', then user can simply choose from this list and make a search.

All part of searching item by selecting from list is clear for me (which pop up when user types first letter, or not if there aren't any data which match it) but now I have a problem, how can I pass this selected input to my master-detail table and execute query which something like :

(SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES E WHERE E.NAME= ??? ) . In '???' should be passed my parameter. How can I do it using PL/SQL?

Comment: It's not clear what your set up is. Does the user enter the search string in a text field, or are they picking a letter from a list item?

Comment: I mention that User types a letter (from keyboard). He can write whole words, but for convenience, i want to show a list within his string

Comment: Yes, that works with both text items and list items.

Comment: But how to pass my input into master-detail? Let's say i want to populate it using master-detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your search item named, e.g. `SEARCH_NAME`:

1. Set the *Default Where* on te employee block to `NAME LIKE :SEARCH_NAME || '%'`
2. When the user picks a value, you would have a trigger or a button they click to do a search. That trigger would have:

   ```
   GO_BLOCK('EMPLOYEE_BLOCK');
   EXECUTE_QUERY;
   ```

Comment: So my search field and employee block should share the same variable , SEARCH_NAME. How can I pass it between each other?

Comment: What do you mean? You don't need to "pass" anything. If it's used by the where clause, when you execute a query on the block it'll take whatever value is in the item at that time.

Comment: Oh I get it, search has One canvas with different win, and my masterdetail has another .It all points in one block, clal it Employee_block. With this logic it should work. Anyway i get an idea, thanks

Comment: You can't have a GO_BLOCK with WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM. Epic fail

Comment: @solvator, thanks, I've removed that suggestion. It is possible, mind you, with a timer.